# Program to find the greatest common divider doesn't work for 15%5

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

Other inputs seem to work fine for finding the result and I was happy about it, but when I put in 15 and 5, the result I get is 0 instead of 5, why is this happening?

From the logic that I can think of, using the comment to follow keep track, it should work fine, but it is not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int m;
int n;
int GCD(int m, int n);
```

```
int main(void)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("M = %d, N = %d", m, n);
    if (m < n) //m = 10, n = 15
    {
        int change = m; //change = 10
        m = n;          //m = 15
        n = change;     // n =10
    }
    printf("\nGCD = %d", GCD(m, n));
}
```

```
int GCD(int m, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        int result = m;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        int save = m; // m = 15, n = 5, save = 15
        m = n;        // m = 5
        n = save % n; //n = 15 % 5 , n = 5
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `15 % 5` would be anything other than zero?

Comment: In think the algorithm should be recursive. `int GCD(int m, int n)
 { if(n==0) return m; else return GCD(n, m%n); }`

Answer (score 1):

About 2300 years ago Euclid of Alexandria figured out how to trivialy calculate the greatest common divisor through a method known as euclidean division also known as division with remainder.

To this day an algorithm appropriately known as *euclidean algorithm* is used to do this calculation, other methods exist today more appropriate for computation [as pointed out by  Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887114/i-made-a-program-to-find-out-the-result-of-155-but-getting-wrong-result-for-15/66887522?noredirect=1#comment118234992_66887522) in the comments, but still, they are based in Euclid's methods.

Here is a possible iterative implementation of the *euclidean algorithm*:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    while b != 0
        t := b
        b := a % b
        a := t
    return a
```

Translating it to C should be equaly trivial, I trust you can make a program based on this algorithm in a matter of minutes.

Comment: It was about 2300 years ago, published in *Elements* circa 300 BCE, book VII, propositions 1 and 2. But there are certainly better methods. The code in this answer does not implement Euclid’s algorithm: Euclid stated it to do a single subtraction at each time, rather than the division-remainder this code uses. However, the [binary GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) is better for computers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if we're being picky *over 2000 years ago* does encompus 2300 years ago ;) I edited my question as to not butcher history.